# Could not resolve '-fx-text-background-color'

Tags: javafx, consola, javafx-css

Estoy haciendo como un proyecto de aprendizaje general, un reproductor de video con las librerías de **JavaFX**. Y al momento de cambiar entre ciertas *Scene* me tira la misma advertencia varias veces.

```
ADVERTENCIA: Could not resolve '-fx-text-background-color' while resolving lookups for '-fx-text-fill' from rule '*.label' in stylesheet jar:file:///C:/javafx-sdk-21.0.2/lib/javafx.controls.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.bss
feb 29, 2024 2:06:01 A. M. javafx.scene.CssStyleHelper calculateValue
```

### intentos

E intentado, borrando de mi pc las librerías y volviéndolas a instalar. Luego con Everything(Motor de búsqueda) eliminé todo archivo que tenga que ver con JavaFX que se haya modificado este año y luego de eso volví a reinstalar las librerías, pero sigue dándome varias veces la advertencia.

PD: Es la primera pregunta que hago por acá, si se necesita más información háganmelo saber en las respuestas porfas. Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: tal vez quieras reportar el error como en https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8088578, igual una sugerencia que he hallado es usar en el código `Platform.runLater`. Si usas una hoja de estilos personalizada se sugiere usar un código de carga imilar a este `StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet(PropertySheet.class.getResource("propertysheet.css").toExternalForm());`

Comment: igual te recomiendo especificar las versiones de tu javafx y de tu jdk

Comment: donde esta tu código?? cual es la estructura del proyecto?? como cargas el css?? y el código en el css?? Así es muy difícil 'Adivinar'

Comment: no encuentro nada con text background color , no será `-fx-background-color` ?